# Access Google Docs Spreadsheet from GWT

Tags: gwt, google-apps

I want to use a Google Docs Spreadsheet as a key-value store from GWT, what is the best way to implement this? I don't think I can use the Google API Client Library for Java since that seems to be a client-side Java library and uses `java.net.HttpURLConnection`. Would I have to use JSNI and the Javascript client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JSNI and the JavaScript client is probably the best way. Another option would be to use the Java client on your server and proxy API calls through it from your client, but that seems unnecessary.